# Jsoup не видит теги

Tags: jsoup, синтаксический-анализ, java, теги, rss

Здравствуйте.
Использую библиотеку Jsoup в своем приложении под Android, но при парсинге RSS не видит тегов, например: `<link>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/</link>`
Использую так:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements links = doc.select("link");
```

Не видит на всех сайтах. Пытался перевести в строку, а потом использовать:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(i.html());
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(i.text());
```

, но все равно не работает.
Не видит именно теги 
Как бы считывает между тегами , но строка всегда пустая.

Что может быть не так?

Проблема решена, спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте вот так:

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).execute.parse();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser())`

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему.